# How to format Lists in Android Studio to stay horizontal?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

[Vertical List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lahdj.png)

I've attached an image as well as copied the same piece of code and pasted it here. I am using Flutter in Android Studio and love the format of Ctrl + Shift + L.. Until now. This list contains 12 elements and I have a total of 24 consecutive lists just like it. So you can see the frustration of scrolling through hundreds of lines to get from top to bottom. Is there some setting in Android Studio that I can change in order for my lists to stay horizontal and default to vertical when I format by Ctrl + Shift + L? 
Thanks for the help.

```
var aquaF = ['12','24','36','48','60','72','84','96','108','120','132','144','156','168','180','192','204','216','228','240','252','264','276','288'];
```

Comment: Just a trailing comma at the end should do it. like `var x = [1,2,];` . For editing multiple list entries in intellij ide: use find and replace(ctrl+h) and search for `];` in the file. Press `alt+enter` for multi-cursor and edit.

Comment: I don’t know where you’re talking about doing this. As in “use find and replace (ctrl+h) and search for ];” Please elaborate? @Bilaal Abdel Hassan

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can get a clean long horizontal line but you can split it up in multiple sections like:

```
var aquaF = [
  '12', '24', '36', '48', '60', '72', '84', '96', '108', '120', '132', '144',
  '156', '168', '180', '192', '204', '216', '228', '240', '252', '264', '276',
  '288' //
];
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62081531/1953515 for the reason of `//`.

Comment: An update on this. I am able to get all of my lists easily back to one horizontal line but selecting all the lines I need and using Ctrl+Shift+J, which is Join Lines in the Edit menu. But... when I reformat lines with Ctrl+Alt+L they return back to vertical. I’ve added // before the ]; and after to keep it from reformatting itself but it still does. Any thoughts?

Comment: I am only using the dartfmt tool to format my code so I don't know if your IDE has some other features to format the code which are doing it in a different way.

Comment: Possibly. Surely there’s a trick to keep it horizontal? 
Thanks anyway!